# ReactTable (ReactJS) - search filtering in row with HTML content does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [ReactTable](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table) and show data from array (array of site url's) as HTML with real links.

Unfortunately search filtering in this column does not work when I use HTML in cell. This is my code for this column:

```
{
Header: 'URL',
accessor: 'url',
Cell: row => <div>{this.displayCellData(row.value, 'url')}</div>
}
```

**displayCellData** is my function that transform Array of urls to HTML string with formatted  tags. **row.value** contain array of urls, like **['http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com/', ...]**

How I can change this code to make filtering for this column works fine? I tried code like this to transform array to string in accessor to make it searchable, but it does not work:

```
{
id: 'url',
Header: 'URL',
accessor: row => row.url.toString(),
Cell: row => <div>{this.displayCellData(row.value, 'url')}</div>
}
```

**ADDED SANDBOX for test:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-mountain-ezxmy (try to search in column)

Comment: Can you show the table code / filter logic?

Comment: In short - just regular table (you can use any sample table for test, with some HTML formatted data in column), init code:

Comment: <ReactTable data={this.props.data} columns={columns} filterable />

Comment: Check sandbox here and try to search: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-mountain-ezxmy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change `defaultFilterMethod` as @arnonuem mentioned. But I would suggest implementing it using the `filterMethod` at the column level

```
  const columns = [
    {
      Header: "URL",
      accessor: "url",
      Cell: row => <div>{displayCellData(row.value)}</div>,
      filterMethod: (filter, row) => {
        return row.url.indexOf(filter.value) >=0;
      }
    }
  ];
```

If you want to search with containing in the array you can use something like below

```
  const columns = [
    {
      Header: "URL",
      accessor: "url",
      Cell: row => <div>{displayCellData(row.value)}</div>,
      filterMethod: (filter, row) => {
        return row.url.findIndex(item => item.indexOf(filter.value) >= 0) >= 0;
      }
    }
  ];
```

Updated sandbox is below

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-rubin-thdwn

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution clear and your second code works fine!

Comment: One more question - how I should modify return row.url.findIndex(item => item.indexOf(filter.value) >= 0) >= 0; code so it will still work if row.url is not a array and just one string (one url instead of array of urls)?

Comment: You can check if `row.url` is a string or is an array. `> Array.isArray("aa")
false` or `Array.isArray(["aa"])
true`

Answer (score 0):

[https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-banach-9l31m](http://Sandbox%20example)

You can overwrite the `defaultFilterMethod` to customize the filter behaviour.

```
<div className="App">
  <ReactTable
    data={data}
    columns={columns}
    filterable
    defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row) => { return row[filter.id].indexOf( filter.value ) > -1; }}
  />
</div>
```

When you now type `http://google.com` it will filter all but the first row based on an exact match. If you need different filter logic then feel free to edit the `defaultFilterMethod`. Currently it's working with exact matches. Just make sure to return a `boolean` value.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom filter method on your respective column like this:

```
filterMethod: (filter, row) => {
   if (row.url.findIndex(element => element.includes(filter.value)) > -1) {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use find  method in your `defaultFilterMethod`  props  with the `includes` function:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "react-table/react-table.css";
import ReactTable from "react-table";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      url: ["http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com/", "http://ggg.com"]
    },
    {
      url: ["http://xgoogle.com", "http://zyahoo.com/", "http://xggg.com"]
    }
  ];
  const columns = [
    {
      Header: "URL",
      accessor: "url",
      Cell: row =>
        row.row.url.map((url, key) => (
          <div>
            <a href={url} key={key} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
              {url}
            </a>
          </div>
        ))
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactTable
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        filterable
        defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row) => {

            return row[filter.id].find(el => el.includes(filter.value));
          }
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```